# Should typescript modules in node_modules be already compiled

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

I've a module made with typescript, I didn't compile it to javascript as I'd like my main application to do so.
Thus I've a file structure like this:

```
my-project
---node_modules
------my-module
---------index.ts
---src
------myfile.ts
```

**myfile.ts**

```
import { x } from 'my-module';
```

**tsconfig**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
        "types": ["reflect-metadata"],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "outDir": "out"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "out"
    ]
}
```

Visual studio code doesn't complain, it finds the module and gives me intellisens. however when running the program I get:

> Error: Cannot find module 'my-module'

While it works just fine when it's an interface that I'm importing. Thus I assume it's because typescript doesn't follow the imports and compile those as well, which I thought it would do.

Do I have to compile my typescript module to javascript before publishing it to npm or is there a setting I can put to not have to ?

PS: It works fine if I compile prior to publishing to npm. I was just wondering: Do I have to do so ?

Answer (score 3):

As a general best practice you should publish your package 'binaries' to npm. With TypeScript, that means the transpiled `.js` files.

This allows a user of your package to consume it without extra complexity of building it. That is, the binaries are directly 'ready for use'.

That said, if you also include the (TS) sources you can still compile them any way you like in the project that depends upon your package. In other words, just because you provide binaries as a convenience, end users have the choice to use the source directly in their projects.

Comment: The tone of your answer seem to hint that it's only best practice but that it should work even without the compiled `.js`. I can compile it prepublishing, however, if it does not work when it's not compiled, it means that the when I do compile it and publish to npm, then when I use the module, it will use the already compiled `.js` and not compile the `.ts`. That's my grip with that because maybe I want to compile it with a different configuration on my second project